# Handling 404 error in asp.net 4.0 with Url routing?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I am using url routing in asp.net 4.0 (web form).

On server, when any user tries to type any url or change the url pattern then i end up with 404 error.

[image: error on server]

How to handle this? Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a custom 404 error page??? We have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: We're going to need the route parameters from the route table and the url typed into the browser at the very least in order see what's wrong.

Comment: when i try to change the url pattern on server then I get the generic IIS7 404 page but i would like redirect to my '404-page-not-found' page. So asking to how to do?

Comment: @welegan: It could be any url. Not specific. if any user tries to change the url pattern and if it doesn't match in route table then i end up with IIS7 404 page (generic)

Answer (score 0):

I see, so this question is about having a custom 404 error page, not why the 404 is coming up for a specific route. In order to handle custom errors in MVC, you can override your controller's

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) { }
```

method. If you are using webforms, then your best bet is to use the web.config's custom errors element. See [msdn documentation for the customErrors web.config element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Example:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Abhishek_cusstom_error.aspx"
          mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
```